# Implement an algorithm to summarize the number of items within buckets of ranges

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that takes an array of numbers (always ascendingly sorted) and an array of buckets where each bucket is a tuple (array of two items) that represents a range (no overlaps). Every adjacent tuple only diff by 1. For example, `[[0, 59], [60, 90]]`. And they are always sorted.

For example,

`summarize( [0, 10, 60, 120],[[0, 59], [60, 90]])` gives us `[2, 1]` because within `[0, 59]` there are two elements `0` and `10` and between `[60, 90]` there is one element `60`.

Here is my attempt:

```js
function summarize(array, buckets) {
  let i = 0
  const results = Array.from({ length: buckets.length }, () => 0)
  for (const item of array) {
    if (item >= buckets[i][0] && item <= buckets[i][1]) results[i]++
    else if (item > buckets[i][1] && i !== buckets.length - 1) {
      if (item <= buckets[i + 1][0]) {
        results[i + 1]++
        i++
        if (i === buckets.length) break
      }
    }
  }

  return results
}
```

The code seems to be working but it looks not clean and brittle. I wonder if there is another way to do it?

Comment: Can the ranges overlap? Are they given in sorted order? Is the first array given in sorted order? How large can the input be? Any constraints?

Comment: @trincot I updated my question descrpition. Thanks!

Comment: The edit leaves a few of my questions unanswered.

Comment: Your code does not always work. For instance: `summarize([9], [[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]])`. So maybe your question should be about the bug(s) in your code.

Comment: @trincot sorry which question you need me to answer?

Comment: Are the ranges given in sorted order? How large can the input be? Any constraints?

Comment: @trincot Every adjacent tuple only diff by 1. For example, [[0, 59], [60, 90]]. And they are always sorted. The array can be really large so we want to minimize the time complexity

Comment: What is the time complexity you want to achieve? Is the first array typically much larger than the number of ranges?

Comment: yea the first array should be large than the number of ranges (i.e. bucket) @trincot I guess the best time complexity we can achieve is still o(n), n being the number of timestamp in the first array?

Comment: The time complexity should be dependent on two dimensions: the size of the first array (n), and the number of buckets (m). The best we can get is O(n+m), because certainly all values of the first array must be visited, and since the output has one entry per bucket, we must also do O(m) work to produce that output.

Comment: @trincot care to write up an answer?

Comment: Wrote up an answer.

Comment: Well as I said below the original code does not work. The condition "if (item <= buckets[i + 1][0])" is not correct. Maybe you should start with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity should be dependent on two dimensions: the size of the first array (n), and the number of buckets (m). The best we can get is O(n+m), because certainly all values of the first array must be visited, and since the output has one entry per bucket, we must also do O(m) work to produce that output.

Your code is aiming for that time complexity, but it has an issue. For instance, the following call will not produce the correct result:

```
summarize([9], [[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]])
```

The issue is that your code is not good at skipping several (more than one) bucket to find the place where a value should be bucketed. Concretely, both `if` conditions can be false, and then nothing happens with the currently iterated value -- it is not accounted for.

Since the output has the same size as the bucket list, we could consider *mapping* the bucket list to the output. Then the `i` index becomes an auxiliary index for the *first* array.

Here is how the code could look:

```js
function summarize(array, buckets) {
    let i = 0;
    return buckets.map(([start, end]) => {
        while (array[i] < start) i++;
        let j = i;
        while (array[i] <= end) i++;
        return i - j;
    });
}

// Example run
console.log(summarize([0, 10, 60, 120],[[0, 59], [60, 90]]));
```

Comment: btw quick question - do yuou know if there is a better name for a function of this use case? I feel like the word `summarize` is to generic. But I couldn't think of a better one.

Comment: Well there's `countPerBucket`, `getBucketFrequencies`,...

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to rely on buckets being both non overlapping AND adjacent.

The code below only requires that each "bucket" array be in ascending order. As it is (with the "break" commented) it doesn't require the numbers to be in any order, and the buckets can overlap, etc.

HTH

```js
function summarize(array, buckets) {

  const results = new Array(buckets.length).fill(0);
  for (i in array) {
    for (j in buckets) {
      if (array[i] >= buckets[j][0] && array[i] <= buckets[j][1]) {
        results[j]++;
        // break;
      }
    }
  }

  return results;
}
console.log(summarize([0, 10, 60, 120], [
  [0, 59],
  [60, 90]
]));
```

Comment: do yuou know if there is a better name for a function of this use case? I feel like the word summarize is to generic. But I couldn't think of a better one

Answer (score -2):

This doesn't require the input or buckets to be sorted and it allows the buckets to overlap:

```
summarize=(a,b)=>b.map(x=>a.filter(y=>y>=x[0]&&y<=x[1]).length)
```

Edit: The `nisetama2` function in the following benchmark requires that the input and buckets are sorted and that the buckets do not overlap:

```
let nisetama=(a,b)=>b.map(x=>a.filter(y=>y>=x[0]&&y<=x[1]).length)

function nisetama2(a,b){
  let min=b[0][0],max=b[0][1],n=0,out=Array(b.length).fill(0)
  for(let i=0,l=a.length;i<l;i++){
    let v=a[i]
    while(v>max){if(n==b.length-1)return out;n++;min=b[n][0];max=b[n][1]}
    if(v>=min)out[n]++
  }
  return out
}

function nistetama2_for_of(a,b){
  let min=b[0][0],max=b[0][1],n=0,out=Array(b.length).fill(0)
  for(let v of a){
    while(v>max){if(n==b.length-1)return out;n++;min=b[n][0];max=b[n][1]}
    if(v>=min)out[n]++
  }
  return out
}

function OP(array, buckets) {
  let i = 0
  const results = Array.from({ length: buckets.length }, () => 0)
  for (const item of array) {
    if (item >= buckets[i][0] && item <= buckets[i][1]) results[i]++
    else if (item > buckets[i][1] && i !== buckets.length - 1) {
      if (item <= buckets[i + 1][0]) {
        results[i + 1]++
        i++
        if (i === buckets.length) break
      }
    }
  }

  return results
}

function WolfD(array, buckets) {
  const results = new Array(buckets.length).fill(0);
  for (i in array) {
    for (j in buckets) {
      if (array[i] >= buckets[j][0] && array[i] <= buckets[j][1]) {
        results[j]++;
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}

function WolfD_let(array, buckets) {
  const results = new Array(buckets.length).fill(0);
  for (let i in array) {
    for (let j in buckets) {
      if (array[i] >= buckets[j][0] && array[i] <= buckets[j][1]) {
        results[j]++;
      }
    }
  }
  return results;
}

function trincot(array, buckets) {
    let i = 0;
    return buckets.map(([start, end]) => {
        while (array[i] < start) i++;
        let j = i;
        while (array[i] <= end) i++;
        return i - j;
    });
}

let a=Array(1e4).fill().map((_,i)=>i)
let b=Array(1e2).fill().map((_,i)=>[i*100,(i+1)*100-1])

let opt=['nisetama','nisetama2','nisetama2_for_of','OP','WolfD','WolfD_let','trincot']
opt.sort(()=>Math.random()-.5)
for(let opti of opt){
  let t1=process.hrtime.bigint()
  eval(opti+'(a,b)')
  let t2=process.hrtime.bigint()
  console.log(t2-t1+' '+opti)
}
```

Here's the median time of a thousand runs in ms (updated to add trincot's function):

```
0.43 trincot
0.67 nisetama2
3.10 nisetama2_for_of
4.03 OP
12.66 nisetama
45.32 WolfD_let
201.55 WolfD
```

Wolf D.'s solution became about 4 times faster when I modified it to use block-scoped variables.

In order to reduce the effect of optimizations for running the same code multiple times, I ran the benchmark like `for i in {0..999};do node temp.js;done` instead of running each option a thousand times inside the script.

Comment: That benchmark is very interesting. Regarding the use of block scoped variables I was asked on another forum to use "classic" Javascript (whatever that may be..) so I was not really paying attention to execution speed, but you're right of course.

Comment: That said, it seems to me, and correct me if I'm wrong, but the OP's code doesn't work at all, in fact. It only seems to work because he uses 60 as a 3rd value, but if you use 62 (for example) it breaks, as it should. The test "if (item <= buckets[i + 1][0])" is not correct.